# Using SAE 10W-30 in both Vehicle and Lawnmower

Tags: oil, small-engine, lawnmower

I have a Toyota vehicle with the [1MZFE engine](http://mywikimotors.com/toyota-1mz/), and have purchased [SAE 10W-30](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Valvoline-Daily-Protection-SAE-10W-30-Conventional-Motor-Oil-Easy-Pour-5-Quart/15125790?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&adid=22222222227008882740&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=40839223832&wl4=pla-52987236926&wl5=9012725&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=online&wl12=15125790&wl13=&veh=sem&gclid=CjwKCAjwndvlBRANEiwABrR32E8ahj1yLbV41RGWo4but7sBPlyrUy2Kp3AFutKHP6ilOAJ6jFiJABoC8dsQAvD_BwE) engine oil to put in this car.

My question is this: Is there a problem with putting this kind of oil in my [Troy-Bilt PowerSmart](https://www.homedepot.com/p/PowerSmart-21-in-3-in-1-161cc-Gas-Walk-Behind-Push-Mower-DB8621P/302569160?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD28I%7C28-35_WALKS%7CNA%7CPLA%7CFixed%7c71700000041070979%7c58700004389671543%7c92700037074991505&gclid=CjwKCAjwndvlBRANEiwABrR32LbFOWRFAw8G1tLE8mTg5V1iX72cHvMsh-7eAUPiS_jmfsU6JsMhzxoCYYAQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) lawnmower? The specifications call for SAE 30, but I was wondering if SAE 10W-30 would be good enough and not give me any trouble with the lawnmower engine.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Same oil in lawnmower, rototiller , chipper shredder, portable generator, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAE-30 is specified as the lawnmower is basically used in summer.

So, using SAE10W-30 will be fine as it has the equivalent hot specification ie the "30" part.

Comment: Actually, it's even better because the engine is not at the operating temperature when you start the lawnmower. I'd bet 10W-30 would cause the small engine to last longer than SAE-30.

Answer (score 0):

The user manual on the OP's web page actually *recommends* 10W-30 oil, for use in all reasonable weather conditions. (I suppose some Canadians might want to mow their lawn when the temperature is below 0F and should use 5W-30 instead, but I wouldn't call that "reasonable"!)

When all else fails, read the documentation: https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/21/215ed4a6-3a98-4685-a7ea-5d5487a1eb2f.pdf Page 12.